# Restricting the options of a lookup field, based on the value of another lookup field?

Tags: lookup

Let's say I have three custom objects: Neighborhood, House, and Room. On the Account object, I have lookup fields for these objects.

My goal: When the user selects a Neighborhood, I want ONLY the houses contained within that neighborhood to be available for selection in the House field. After a house is selected, I want ONLY the rooms contained within that house to be available for selection in the Room field. Is there any way to do this?

I have already learned that there are ways to do this in a custom Lightning page. However, I'm looking for a way to do this with custom fields on a regular Salesforce object, like Account.

Answer (score 3):

Disclaimer: I haven't tried it out myself, but going through the docs, it seems like you can utilize [Dependent Lookups](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=fields_lookup_filters_dependent_lookups.htm&type=5) here.

> A ***dependent lookup*** is a relationship field with a [lookup filter](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=fields_lookup_filters.htm&type=5) that references fields on the source object. For example, you can configure the case `Contact` field to only show contacts associated with the account selected in the case `Account Name` field.

You will need to utilize `Inserted Suggested Criteria` when [defining Lookup Filters](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=fields_lookup_filters.htm&type=5) to be able to utilize this.

> When you define a lookup filter, optionally click `Insert Suggested Criteria` to choose from a list of lookup filter criteria that Salesforce suggests based on the relationships between objects in your org.

So in your case you will have a filter on your `Household` lookup to filter results based on the `Neighborhood` field and similarly a filter on your `Room` field to filter results based on the `Household` field.

Answer (score 2):

Your **House** object should have a lookup to a **Neighborhood**. Your **Room** object should have a lookup to a **House**.

Then on the **Account** you can add filters to your **House** and **Room** lookup fields as follows:

House Lookup Filter that ensures that this house is in the same neighborhood that is specified on the account record
[image: House Lookup Filter that ensures that this house is in the same neighborhood that is specified on the account record]

Room Lookup Filter that ensures this room is in the same house that is specified on the account
[image: Room Lookup Filter that ensures this room is in the same house that is specified on the account]